# undefined method email for NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm getting the following error:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #14):

```
<ul>
<li><h5><%= newsletter.name if newsletter.image.present? %></h5></li>
By: <%= @user.email if @user.email.present? %>  <--- line 14
```

It's related to this code:

```
<% @newsletters.each do |newsletter| %>
  <% @user = newsletter.user %>

<ul>
  <li><h5><%= newsletter.name if newsletter.image.present? %></h5></li>
  By: <%= @user.email if @user.email.present? %>
  <li><%= image_tag newsletter.image.url(:medium) if newsletter.image.present? %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Ultimately, I'd like to show the owner of the newsletters email address. Why isn't this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when your newsletter doesn't have a user. You should check if the user exists before displaying the user email.

```
<ul>
  <li><h5><%= newsletter.name if newsletter.image.present? %></h5></li>
  <%if @user && @user.email.present? %>
    By: <%= @user.email %>
  <% end %>
  <li><%= image_tag newsletter.image.url(:medium) if newsletter.image.present? %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is no user present. You can either use @Vimsha's solution. Or try this:

```
<ul>
  <li><h5><%= newsletter.name if newsletter.image.present? %></h5></li>
    By: <%= @user.try(:email) %>
  <li><%= image_tag newsletter.image.url(:medium) if newsletter.image.present? %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten the answer to this: the user doesn't exist for a newsletter. To fetch only those newsletters that have a user, I suggest you join the table with the user e.g.

```
@newsletters = Newsletter.where(conditions).all # what you're doing now - just an example
@newsletters = Newsletter.joins(:user).where(conditions).all # will exclude newsletters that don't have a user
```